# Is it possible to add hosting to some image hosting in share menu?

Tags: macos, sharing, screen-capture

I have a MacBook Pro. I can make screenshots. It lands on the desktop. By opening the context menu I can press the Share button.

Is it possible to add some button which will share the image on some image hosting? For example, I had Gyazo on Windows and now I use Lightshot. I can select region of my screen and picture immediately hosts on the server and link to the image is in my buffer.

I mean this menu:

[image]

Is this possible on Mac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**ImageShareUr**](https://www.simplicate.info/imageshareur/) which adds a share extension for uploading to Imgur.

Choose More to enable the extension for the first use, then you can select an image and choose Share → Upload to Imgur and follow the instructions.

[image]
[image]

Despite the author's message on the page that it doesn't work in Sierra, I've just tried it on 10.12.4 and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

**ImageShareUr** seems to have been abandoned, and the simplicate website is offline. (Though you can still get a copy of the app from the WayBackMachine.)

I found another software called **[imGuru](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/imguru/id1012308785?mt=12)** which is for free on the AppStore. However, the app fails to copy the image URL to the clipboard on my system, and it doesn't support anonymous upload like **ImageShareUr** does (did), which I always thought was a great feature.

Another app is **[iPic](https://en.toolinbox.net/iPic/)**, also for free on the MAS, but you need to buy the Pro license (in-app purchase) to get imgur support. Downsides: doesn't support anonymous upload either, and it's not available via the "Share" menu.

Still looking for a good replacement for **ImageShareUr** with free imgur support, anonymous uploading, and "Share" menu integration.